# How to download file from api in react native

Tags: react-native, api, axios, imagedownload

I am getting the file-like image in the response of the API then I need to download that image in mobile storage but when I was researching I didn't find the way to download a file there is the way's to download images when you have downloadable URL but I don't have that. can anyone help with that "data": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object],"blobId": "a3432f49-13a1-4e2b-873d-a4dce3b71191","offset": 0,"size": 142788}} this is the response if i am using  responseType: 'blob' in my api header[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this lib https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util to download any file including images

Comment: i tried this before but didn't worked for me

Comment: "data": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object],"blobId": "a3432f49-13a1-4e2b-873d-a4dce3b71191","offset": 0,"size": 142788}},
this is response of api
@DiveDive

Comment: @AbdullahBilalKhanzada, Did you resolve it? If yes, then how?